# Best way for a component that takes route parameters and Inputs?

Tags: angular

Let me explain my problem using a DVD Management App as an example, we have a detail view which takes route parameters from `/dvd/:id` by using ActivatedRoute in our `DvdInfoComponent` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dvdService.getById(
        this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']
    ).subscribe(dvd => { this.dvd = dvd; });
}
```

Now let's assume that we want to include this component inside an other component, maybe in an accordeon with one extension bar for each dvd. Let's call it `DvdListComponent`. We want to use it like that

```
<!-- *ngFor stuff -->
<app-dvd-info [id]="dvdId"></app-dvd-info>
```

For this to work we need an `@Input`, in some cases we need a setter, which looks like this

```
@Input() set id(id: string) {
    this.dvdService.getById(id).subscribe(dvd => { this.dvd = dvd; });
}
```

And here comes my problem, if I have both solutions in my component, one will overwrite the result of the other. Even if I would check whether the id parameter exists before getting the dvd in the `ngOnInit()` function, theoretically it could be the id of a different component like `/collection/:id`. How can I use the Component in both ways? Or do I have to manage two similar copies of the DVD Component just for that purpose?

Comment: Do you intend to fetch the DVD info when either the component is initialized as well as when the id changes?

Comment: Yes, usually it wouldn't switch between using the `@Input` and the `:id` parameter. When using `@Input` it would have to update even after initialization, when using the `:id` parameter it has to render only during initialization because when the parameter changes angular would re-render the page, thus create a new component instance and discard the old one.

Comment: I am still not able to understand what you intend to do? It is hard to decipher from your question what problem you are facing! Is it like you want the `id` field as `@Input` and when using a setter, it is changing its (`id`) value. Does this make sense?

Comment: When the `DvdInfoComponent` gets rendered by the `router-outlet` directly, it should take the url parameter `:id`, on the other hand when being imported by another component using its selector, it should use the `@Input` argument being passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kind of situation its better to use "Smart Components vs Presentational Components".
Smart Components: also know sometimes as application-level components, container components or controller components.
Presentation Components: also known sometimes as pure components or dumb components.

Please find the link
[Angular Architecture - Smart Components vs Presentational Components](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/)

Comment: After further reading that is actually a good architecture, although I do have to create more components for this to work, considering separation of concern it is probably the best solution. Thanks for the hint.
But this article is better in my eyes: https://blog.wishtack.com/2017/05/05/the-guide-to-building-quality-angular-2-components/

Comment: Thanks @Vic for this question, I face the exact same issue. Unfortunately your link on wishtack no longer works (at least for me). Could you please publish another link, or explain how you finally proceeded? Many thanks!

Comment: @bfredo123 you can find it in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20220122064057/https://blog.wishtack.com/2017/05/05/the-guide-to-building-quality-angular-2-components/

Answer (score 0):

By understanding your problem, could you try the below code:-

```
ngOnInit() {
    // first check if id is used as @Input otherwise set id from URL.
    const id = this.id || this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.dvdService.getById(id).subscribe(dvd => { this.dvd = dvd; });
}
```

You may check whether the `id` exists as `@Input` value and if it doesn't exist, get it from the URL.

`const id = this.id || this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];`

**You need to remove the setter function in this case.**

Comment: But that wouldn't solve the issue since I get the semantically wrong parameter for this component when nested in a different one like `/collection/:id`, of couse you could say to just use a unique name like `/collection/:collectionId` but that may not be possible or result in a huge amount of work changing this in large projects.

Comment: Also this example here is just a simple use case, but there are others which require a setter function where removing it is not an option.

Comment: @Vic  - Kindly note, we are not here to make it semantically correct for you. That is up to you to decide the naming convention and the process you would want to follow. Those were the variable names that you used and now you are saying it didn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a safe way to handle both cases, is to have in ngOnInit:

```
if (this.myInput) {
  // initialize from the myInput @Input attribute
  stuff = this.myInput
}
else {
  // initialize from the routeParams
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    stuff = params.get('myInputParam')
  }
}
```

However, this would not work for optional params, because then, the test on myInput does not help determining whether the component was invoked from another component with no attribute set, or invoked by routing.